# Saved data getting replaced by new data on app relaunch

Tags: ios

I am making a calorie counter which displays the total calorie count of various foods added. I have written code to save data following this [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-6-saving-data/). When I relaunch the app I can see the calorie count is the same as when I quit the app but when I add a new food item, the calorie count is reset and the count begins from the start. Why is the value not being saved??

EDIT:

This is a snippet of my code:

```
if(alertView.tag == ChickenAlertView) {

        NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]){

            float chicken= ([ChickenText.text floatValue]);
            currentnumber = (chicken/100)*219;
            result = result + currentnumber;
            calories.text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.f",result];
        }
    }
```

From NSLog, i can see the value of result is going to 0 every time I relaunch the app. How do I prevent it?

This is where I save the code:

```
- (NSString *) saveFilePath {  

NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];  

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { 

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: NameLabel.text, AgeLabel.text, HeightLabel.text, WeightLabel.text, BMILabel.text, calories.text, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:result], nil];

[values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
[values release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

foodData = [[foodData alloc]init];

NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath]; 

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

if (fileExists)
{

    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    NameLabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
    AgeLabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:1]
    HeightLabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:2];
    WeightLabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:3];
    BMILabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:4];
    calories.text = [values objectAtIndex:5];
    result = [[values objectAtIndex:6] floatValue];

    [values release];
}

UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:myApp];

[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: That code is kind of meaningless. What about the code where you actually save your changes?

Comment: @TomHarrington - Please check my edit. I have added the entire code to save and load the data.